# Creating thumbnail failed redmine

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby, thumbnails, redmine

Need help on the thumbnail failed to find have no idea anymore how to fix this.

In issue if you add the attachment it doesn't show small image of entered image but the link to image working as it should just doesn't show the small image as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

In log it says:

```
Started GET "/attachments/thumbnail/7" for 111.111.1.11 at 2021-09-06 17:01:57 +0300
Processing by AttachmentsController#thumbnail as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
Creating thumbnail failed (pid 97475 exit 1):
Command: '/usr/local/bin/convert' '/usr/local/www/redmine/files/2021/09/210901111738_4.jpg' -auto-orient -thumbnail '1000x1000>' '/usr/local/www/redmine/tmp/thumbnails/a78495fde3baccb50ef5da33a2de8a95c7c6aea5106ce804d6b8b9275f44626c_462889_1000.thumb'
Completed 404 Not Found in 203ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Environment:

- Redmine version                4.1.2.stable
- Ruby version                   2.7.3-p183 (2021-04-05) [amd64-freebsd13]
- Rails version                  5.2.6
- Environment                    production
- Database adapter               Mysql2

Maybe the thumbnail href is bad but no idea were to check were the code is because in attachments/_links.html.erb

```
<% if defined?(thumbnails) && thumbnails %>
  <% images = attachments.select(&:thumbnailable?) %>
  <% if images.any? %>
  <div class="thumbnails">
    <% images.each do |attachment| %>
      <div><%= thumbnail_tag(attachment) %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but this looks good only the line of thumbnail_tag(attachment) no idea were this directs and were all this files/images saves maybe the problem is because it doesn't save image in that folder which it needs to be saved and again were it should be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got it
Gemfile in 13th line must be written like this and check for ownershhip of TMP folder

`gem "mimemagic"`